# Blackberry Development version 7 and lover, signing key error : server unavailable at this time. please contact your system administrator

Tags: blackberry, key, signing

When I try to sign the key it returns an error "server unavailable at this time. please contact your system administrator"

I tried to use a proxy as it was advised in one blackberry support site, used myproxy.com port:80 and it returned the same error. Any idea how I can solve this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Signing servers are down sometimes (mostly for maintenance purposes), you can check their status on this web-site:

http://isthesigningserverdown.com/

Comment: Hello. I checked this page and every ip was in SUCCESS state. Then I tried again to sign the key but it returned the same error.

Comment: I assume you do not have a blocking firewall on your network, then send an email to `devsupport@rim.com` and describe your issue.